# Accessing GitLab access token in Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, plugins, gitlab-api

I have built a Jenkins custom plugin that access Git repos (GitLab) that requires a username and associated GitLab access token. That is fine. But in Jenkins Credentials page, there is already an entry created for GitLab API token for webhook and a username. I would like to use the token in the Credentials page instead of defining in the plugin myself. How can I programmatically extract the credential entry from my Jenkins plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question:

```
    private String getGitLabAccessToken(String username) {

    List<Credentials> credentials = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider
        .getInstance()
        .getCredentials();

    for (Credentials c : credentials) {

        if (c instanceof GitLabApiTokenImpl) {
            if (((GitLabApiTokenImpl) c).getId().toString().equals(username)) {
                return ((GitLabApiTokenImpl) c).getApiToken().getPlainText();
            }

        } //if

    } //for

    return null;
}
```